# Core 1.5.1 Throws Warning on IE Input type email check after updating to latest chrome

Tags: mootools, google-chrome-devtools

Since upgrading to Chrome 41.0.2272.89 m, Mootools Core 1.5.1 is throwing a warning. Nothing major, but if you are as retentive as I am, it may irk you a little.

```
var input = document.createElement('input'), volatileInputValue, html5InputSupport;

// #2178
input.value = 't';
input.type = 'submit';
volatileInputValue = input.value != 't';

// #2443 - IE throws "Invalid Argument" when trying to use html5 input types
try {
    input.type = 'email';
    html5InputSupport = input.type == 'email';
} catch(e){}
```

Throws warning:

> The specified value 't' is not a valid email address.

Comment: Just saw a fix in github [here](https://github.com/lyzzard/mootools-core/commit/9f374e8709358ceffa51375ffa841d083c315120). Not sure how long until this is up on Mootools though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix, change the try catch above to:

```
try {
    input.value = '';
    input.type = 'email';
    html5InputSupport = input.type == 'email';
} catch(e){}
```

Or in the compressed version , search for "email" and change this:

```
try{p.type="email",h="email"==p.type}catch(c){}
```

To:

```
try{p.value="",p.type="email",h="email"==p.type}catch(c){}
```

Comment: as commented above, there is a fix coming: [Git](https://github.com/lyzzard/mootools-core/commit/9f374e8709358ceffa51375ffa841d083c315120)

Comment: ... and Arian just merged it today. `+1`